# Cron job to delete unmodified files from within folder (and possibly leave some untouched)

Tags: cron

I've got a basic idea I've pieced together from different sources, but each seems to be a bit different (eg. rm/find and mktime -1/+1 seem to be variations), so I'm just wondering if I'm doing this right, or if there's a better way to do it?

The code is here -

```
php -f /home/(my username)/   - I can't edit that part
rm -f public_html/thumb/cache/* -mtime +1
```

I'd like it to run every day, and preferably not destroy the entire site, would this work alright?

Also, one more question, if the cache folder has one file I'd like to keep, is it also possible to add something extra to not delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`, like:

```
find /usr/local/www/public_html/thumb/cache/ -type f -mtime +1d -delete
```

This will delete all files older than 1day in specified path.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, though it still comes up with the error 'Path to the script cannot contain any special symbols or whitespaces'. I suppose I'm going to have to wait until someone decides to post on the forum with what's going on, cheers for the help though :)

Comment: Oh, just got it working, turns out you can't do a cron job, you can only type in the location of a file. I've stuck the code inside a file, just gotta wait 12 hours to see if it works :)
If not, cheers for your answer on the other question too, I'll try the php code you linked to :P